# IR camera LED flashing constantly

Tags: hardware, webcam, camera, peripherals

My laptop has an embedded IR camera. According to HP specs, it is an HP Wide Vision FHD IR Camera. Whenever I use it, the IR LEDs flicker constantly (five times a second at lest).

I can't use the IR camera, because the light needs to be solid, so that it illuminates the room in the IR spectrum. How can I keep it from flickering?

Comment: I have the same problem @mason-jones. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @broccoli no, I ended up getting a different computer. I did find a way to disable the IR camera though, so the default camera would be the color one. [This](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1980995) article explains how to do it. Sorry!